# pandas add sql table, check if table exists

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have this piece of code that loops for excel files in a directory, add the file in a sqlite db .
I managed to get past the exception raised if the table exists but I find this inelegant and inefficient since the loop reads the excel file, add it in a Dataframe, etc...
what ideally i would like is that I test the existence of the table before creating the df from excel.

```
response = {}
for f in glob('T:\GESTION\toto\titi\tata\file_201*.xlsx'):
    print f
    datereg = re.search('T:\\\\GESTION\\\\toto\\\\titi\\\\tata\\\\file_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).xlsx', f)
    if datereg is not None:
        dated = datetime.datetime(int(datereg.group(1)), int(datereg.group(2)), int(datereg.group(3)))
    print dated

    # ideally test if table in db exists here

    xl = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    df = xl.parse(sheetname="Sheet1")
    df = df[extractFields].drop_duplicates(subset='ISIN')
    df = df.set_index('ISIN', verify_integrity=True)
    response[dated] = df
    # print response
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///my_db.sqlite')
    try:
        df.to_sql(dated.__str__(), engine, if_exists='fail')
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
        pass
```

Comment: Why not just create an empty df after you generate your `dated` datetime and test at that point, this is before you even read the excel file and then call `df.to_sql` at that point

Comment: when you say test at that point do you mean use the try: except on the empty df ?

Comment: with `engine.has_table('table_name')` you can check if a table already exists

Answer (score 5):

This is what i have for my bit of code:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}".format(user="root",pw="password",db="worker"))
check=engine.has_table(table_name)
            print(check) #boolean
            if check == False:
                df.to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

From sqlalchemy 1.4, `has_table` is now called from `Inspector` object.

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.has_table)

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect, create_engine

engine = create_engine('...')
insp = inspect(engine)
table_exist = insp.has_table(table_name, schema)

if table_exist:
    df.to_sql(name, engine)
```